# Lines in sprites flicker when moving

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

We are creating a game in flutter flame and we notice some strage jitter whenever we move our camera. We have a position component that moves by changing the position and the camera follows

We have very simple movement for now where dt is delta time inside the Player component that extends PositionComponent

```
  void update(double dt) {
    if (position.distanceTo(moveTarget) > 0.1) {
      final moveDirection = moveTarget - position;
      moveDirection.normalize();
      position += moveDirection * dt * speed.toDouble();
    }
    super.update(dt);
  }
```

and this is the camera

```
 camera.followComponent(player);
```

But our sprite has alot of jitter. The lines of the sprite flicker. We will be using pixel art but this is just an example sprite to illustrate

[image]

What causes this?

Movement on 1 axis seem to work better but still

[image]

We are running this on flutter web with flutter version 2.8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably caused by [Flutter's anti aliasing bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14288).

If you use a sprite without lines like that in the middle you shouldn't notice it, as can be seen on the component that is solid teal in your example.

Comment: It's the stangest thing. It seems to happen on my co-workers laptop but not on my own. We are using flutter web but switching browser does not seem to make any difference.

Comment: It depends a lot on size and resolution since it basically is a rounding error causing it.

Comment: Aah okay, we just got a constract for a big pixel art game and decided to use flame instead of pixi.js. But making a pixel art game with this bug seems impossible, to no fault of flame ofc.

Comment: Have you tried with another sprite? It is a quite rare issue after all, and the sprite you are using doesn't look like something that you will use in the end?

Comment: Yes we have but the problem is that I cannot upload the art on stackoverflow. I will try to find some sprites that demonstrate the problem a bit better this weekend.

Comment: Please join our discord and we can discuss the problem more thoroughly. :)
https://discord.com/invite/pxrBmy4